# Does a planar triangulation always contain a Hamiltonian path?

Tags: co.combinatorics

What about a Hamiltonian path in a triangulation of an n-gon? If not, how long is the longest path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two planar triangulations on 14 vertices without hamiltonian paths. This is the smallest size. For sure these are well-known.

[image: no hamiltonian path]

Those answer the question for $n=3$. For $n=4$ the first examples appear at 12 vertices. Same for $n=5$. For $n=6$ one with 10 vertices. For $n=7$ one with 11 vertices.  And so forth.

Answer (score 7):

It is a famous theorem of
Whitney (1931<sup>*</sup>) that
a $4$-connected planar triangulation has a Hamiltonian cycle.

---

[image]

          

<sup>Example of *non*-Hamiltonian triangulation from [Joseph Malkevitch](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78835/237), 


              
obviously not $4$-connected: removing $3$ vertices (surrounding one) disconnects.


             
(A graph is $4$-connected if it requires removal of $4$ vertices to disconnect it.)</sup>

---

> <sup>*</sup>
>   H Whitney.
>   A theorem on graphs.
>   *Ann. of Math.*, 32 (1931), pp. 378–390.

In response to the OP's query:

---

[image: TriNoHP]

          

<sup>A connected triangulated graph with no Hamiltonian path.</sup>

---

Perhaps the OP may be interested in this paper:

> Arkin, Esther M., Martin Held, Joseph SB Mitchell, and Steven S. Skiena. "Hamiltonian triangulations for fast rendering." *The Visual Computer*. 12, No. 9 (1996): 429-444.
>   
>   ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01782475#page-1).)

Comment: Thank you for the reference! But what about Hamiltonian path?

Comment: I should clarify that by a planar triangulation I mean this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangulatedGraph.html The second example is not a planar triangulation.

Comment: The answer is still *No*, but now you need a maximal planar triangulated graph with at least $8$ "separating triangles." This is easily constructed, and it has no Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 5):

See the answer to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78784/trivial-example-of-a-non-hamiltonian-planar-triangulation) The magic word is "Kleetope". For more information than you imagined possible, see [Guido Helden's Thesis.](http://d-nb.info/985331496/34)